# Would hibernate + spring data jpa would create a record automatically child entity of its parent entity having with OneToOne relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In a shop where I spend 8 hrs a day, I work with jsf 2.x web application. In it, hibernate + spring data jpa work together for Database transaction.

I share water downed version of `Foo` java entity in that web application.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FOO")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @Column(name="FOO_ID", nullable=false)
    private UUID fooId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="Foo", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
       orphanRemoval=true)
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Bar bar;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="Foo", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, 
       orphanRemoval=true)
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private Zoo zoo;

    }
```

As you see java entity `Foo` and `Bar` has `OneToOne` relationship. From UI side, when I come to a page in where I need to fill out a form, data I would fill out for that form would create `Foo` instance and one of child instance `Bar` or `Zoo`. Once you complete the form, there is `CrudRepository.save(foo)` only exit entrance for persisting `Foo` instance to database. Its associated child entity either `Bar` or `Zoo` would be encapsulated in `Foo` instance.

Here is a peculiar incident I ran into:

1. Fill out the form and save it which in turn would create a record for `Foo` and `Bar` instance in each table `FooTable` and `BarTable` respectively in DB.
2. There is no record found in `ZooTable` which is expected.
3. I revisit same `Foo` instance from web app THEN something odd happened.
4. I noticed a record is created in `ZooTable` only primary key of itself `zoo_id` and its parent as foreign key `foo_id` but rest of columns which map to form data as NULL.

I put a break point in `save()` method in the application expecting when the page is loaded I expected it would be hit but it never did. It looks like application is bypassing proper exit entrance to persist to DB but rather using a hidden back door to go out and persist to DB.

I am trying to find an answer for it but I have not been successful. I read a few articles about `jpa auto save` in here but neither I fully understand nor cases they presented match with my scenario.

My guess is it has to do with `OneToOne` relationship between `Foo` and its child entity `Bar` or `Zoo`. When you revisit `Foo` instance, it would expect missing child entity would be fetched(?) but since it is not found either hibernate or spring data jpa alone or working together would create a phantom entry?

Comment: I don't know where this `LazyCollection` comes from, but be aware that it the JPA way to do that is `@OneToOne(fetch = LAZY)`.

Comment: If you have getters and setters put a breakpoint in `setZoo()` and see what is calling it. It cannot appear out of nowhere ;)

Comment: Absolutely. I have no doubt `setter` would be invoked to set its value however it should not persist it to DB at that point. `CrudRepository.save(foo)` should create an entry after it is executed. Until then I can only manage (create or update) state of `Foo` or either of or both of `Bar` `Zoo` entities. The only exit entry to get to DB is via `CrudRepository` but it looks like there is a back door to get to DB but it seems like it is triggered ONLY for a certain condition.

Comment: From thorough observation of this app, myself and other sr. engineer begin to believe that JPA/Hiberate `OneToOne` annotation may triggering unexpected behavior at least in our point of view, If either of `Bar` or `Zoo` entry from DB is missing once its parent `Foo` is revisited/loaded again. It would create an entry of missing child entity. Interestingly enough if I select both `Bar` and `Zoo` at the beginning of `Foo` instance then I revisit same `Foo` instance again, there is no unwanted behavior is observed. Our team suspects `OneToOne` relationship may play a role behind this.

Comment: @chrylis: I tried with JPA way as you suggested by playing with `fetchType.LAZY` and `fetchType.EAGER` but either way didn't make any difference. But ty for your advice in regards to proper way of using annotation.